# Implicit Differentiation usage of $\frac {dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Why,  after differentiating $y$ on one side of the equation, is $dy/dx$ added?
As clarification an example I will provide an example:

Implicitly differentiate $y^2 = x$.

You get $$2y\frac {dy}{dx} = 1$$ as one of the first steps in differentiation.  Why is the $dy/dx$ added after $y^2$ is differentiated?

Thanks!

Comment: because of the chain rule, $y$ is a function of $x$ and so the derivative of $y$ is $1$ multiplied by its derivative, which is $y'$

Comment: @Ethan $y^2=x$ is abuse of notation for $\left(y(x)\right)^2=x$. Just apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^2=(y(x))^2=x\\
\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}=1\\
\implies \dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}=\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}\text{ (chain rule )}=1\\
\implies 2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=1$$

Comment: When you get $\frac{d(y^2)}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}$, wouldn't the $dy$ cancel leaving $\frac{d(y^2)}{dx} = 2y$ ?

Comment: @Ethan $$\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2y\boxed{\dfrac{dy}{dx}}$$Of course, you can cancel out the $dy$s, but what do you get? You get $\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}$, which is what you began with.

Comment: So because there are no $x$s in $\frac{d(y^2)}{dx}$, you can differentiate with respect to $y$ giving you $2y$ ?

Comment: @Ethan Let me give an example. Let $y=x+1$. Then, $y^2=x^2+1+2x$. Then, $$\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}=\dfrac{d(x^2+1+2x)}{dx}=2x+2\\ \dfrac{d(y^2)}{dx}=\dfrac{d(y^2)}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2(x+1)(1)=2x+2$$See that both are equal.

Comment: In the second half of the example when you get $2y \frac{dy}{dx}$ how did $\frac{dy}{dx}$ simplifying to $1$?

Comment: @Ethan $y=x+1$, so $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dx}{dx}+\dfrac{d(1)}{dx}=1+0=1$.

Comment: Why does dy/dx equal dx/dx PLUS d(1)/dx?  Shouldn't It be times, not plus?

Comment: @Ethan No, since $y=x+1$, and $$\dfrac{d(f+g)}{dx}=\dfrac{df}{dx}+\dfrac{dg}{dx}$$So, take $f(x)=x,g(x)=1$.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I understand.  Just to clarify though,  if there is only $y$ as a variable and you are differentiating $dy/dy$, then you can just differentiate normally?

Comment: By normally, I mean $dy/dy$ of $y^2$ is just $2y$?

Comment: @Ethan Yes,$$\dfrac{dy^2}{dy}=2y$$

Comment: alright, I understand now,  thank you for your help.

Comment: @Ethan Sure!${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind implicit differentiation is that while $y$ isn't (necessarily) a *function* of $x$ we treat it as it it was.

So say that $y = f(x)$. Then you want to find $f'(x)$ in the following $$f(x)^2 = x.$$ So you take the derivative on both sides and use the chain rule to find the derivative of $f(x)^2$:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} f(x)^2 &= \frac{d}{dx} x & \Rightarrow \\
2f(x)f'(x) &= 1 
\end{align}
$$
Now then we just replace $f(x)$ by $y$ and get
$$
2y\frac{dy}{dx} = 1.
$$
So to answer you question about where the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ comes from, you can think of it as the derivative of the inner function $y$.